# Xamarin Android, use MySQL Plugin to insert image into db field

Tags: android, sql, database, image, xamarin

I'm fairly new to Xamarin and I've got MySQL working, inserting data into a database. What I want to be able to do is take an image and store that as text which I can then decode. I know it's not necessarily the best way of doing things but that's my plan. I'm just not sure how to convert a jpeg to a string.

Hope you can help.

Comment: you can convert it to a byte[] and store as a BLOB, or Base64 encode it to store as text

Comment: How would I do this? Can you give me a code snippet?

Comment: both approaches are well documented elsewhere on SO and the web

Comment: Brill thanks, Would this work then?
 public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
 {
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
       imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
       return  ms.ToArray();
    }
 }

Comment: Android does not support System.Drawing.Image

Comment: Would this be better?

public static byte[] converterDemo(Image x)
{
    ImageConverter _imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
    byte[] xByte = (byte[])_imageConverter.ConvertTo(x, typeof(byte[]));
    return xByte;
}

Comment: I still can't seem to find a script that would allow me to convert a jpeg to text and back again. The only ones I've found use imports that I don't seem to be able to find.